# PHP - list all index files in dynamic sub-directories

Tags: php, html

I am creating multiple individual and static HTML-Pages in there’re own directories for Homework etc., and since I am lazy I do not want to always update my main Index page, so is it possible (and I know it is) to list those files via PHP?

And what more important is, is how I would do that…

Comment: "is it possible (and I know it is) to list those files via PHP?"

Sounds like you answered your own question!

Comment: A... [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:  glob() [php.net/glob](http://php.net/glob)